# Creating a view for related content types

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-views

I'm creating 2 content types: 'Event' and 'Speaker'. An event has multiple speakers.
For the relation I'm using the entity reference module. 
I want to make a view where I can see an event with the speakers' information, picture, ..
Someone told me to use display suite too, but I don't really know why I would need this.
What would be the best approach?

Thanks in advance for your help! :)
Simon

Answer (score 0):

You can definitely do this with views: display the fields of a referenced node in a view.

Create a view that displays all the fields you want from your event, but then, to be able to pull the appropriate speaker fields for that event, you'll have to add that speaker relationship.

1. Go to the 'Advanced' section of your view and click on 'Add' next to '**Relationships**'
2. Select 'Content: Speaker' or whatever the exact name of your referenced field is
3. Now you should be able to see and select any of the 'speaker' field from the field list, but make sure when you choose one of the speaker fields, that you select for the 'Speaker' relationship to be used when displaying it.  It's an option on the field settings page.

Does that work for you?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do this with Views.

But since you're using the Entity relationships, you need to add two relationships in your view.  One for the relationship from 'Event' to the 'Entity' and another from the 'Entity' to the 'Speaker'.  It's like adding a Many-to-Many join table.

1. Make a view of Events
2. Make an Entity relationship between Events and Speakers
3. Add a relationship between Event and the Entity Relationship
4. Add another relationship to Speakers that uses the relationship from step 3
5. Add whatever fields you need from the Speakers nodes.

Hope that helps. I got stuck on that for a long time myself.

The main issue is going to be managing 'duplicates' if you have more than a 1:1 relationship.  You might be able to manage that with the "Use Aggregation" feature.

An alternative I came up with for an outdoor activities site I was working on ( http://dev.naturefitter.com/packages ) that avoided the duplication issue was to use Views Field View ( http://drupal.org/project/views_field_view/ ).  I created a main view (in my case 'Packages') and a subsequent sub view ('Activities') that takes a contextual filter from the main view.  The sub view is a block that has the fields from the Activity content type and a contextual filter that expects the nid from the package content it's attached to.

Best,

Pat