# Show related users on user page

Tags: drupal-7, drupal-views

On the user page (/user/20 for example) I want to display a view with some related users. Each user has a field of type entity reference that points to a user. The users are related if they point to the same user.

I tried to do this using the Entity Views Attach module, but didn't succeed (although I think it should be possible using it).

Could someone give me some advice on how I could do this?

Answer (score 0):

I would create an block (or eva) view using contextual filters with your reference field that takes the uid from the url (or node's author) as parent.

maybe this other [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11956167/1437542) can help

PR